# Regex pattern to match using starts with and ends with a word(start word multiple occurrence)

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a string say "Explain STARThow you STARTencountered the problem you’reSTART trying to solveEND, and anySTART difficulties that STARThave prevented you fromEND solving it yourself."

I have this pattern: @"START.*?END";

But when I evaluate and match this I am getting:
"STARThow you STARTencountered the problem you’reSTART trying to solveEND"
and
"START difficulties that STARThave prevented you fromEND"

What I need is to get the occurrence where the START word is closest to the END word:
"START trying to solveEND"
and
"STARThave prevented you fromEND"

Comment: You need a tempered greedy token `START(?:(?!START).)*END` https://regex101.com/r/A98LLQ/1

Comment: Use: `START(?:(?!START).)*?END` ... [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/JTbxII/1)

Comment: Thanks guys that was fast. Those suggestions Answers my questions!

Comment: Glad we could help